# String List into SQL

Tags: java, android

Topic: (Android / Java +SQLite)

My app looks like this: there is a Thumbnail in a ListView containing data from my sql-table, clicking on it, it will display all the names connected to this thumbnail.
I'm reading out a server response (basically a JSON) in my reader.class:

```
JSONObject json = myjsonfromserver.getJSONObject(i);
String jr_thumbnail = json.getString("thumbnail");

JSONArray names = json.getJSONArray("name");

String[] nmslist = new String[names.length()];

                                for(int i=0; i<names.length(); i++)
                                {
                                    nmslist[i]=nms.optString(i);
                                }
                                for(int j=0;j<names.length;j++){
                                    nmslist.add(arr[j]);
                                }
```

Let's move to my problem: The names list hasn't a fixed length but let's fix a number around 150 as max names length. Inserting it into a SQL Table gives me headache:

```
String SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO names_table (id,thumbnail,name(1),name(2),name(3)...) VALUES('"+i+"',...)
```

Do I have to write 150 times the names() coloumn in the SQLQuery or is there any faster way do do that, maybe with a for-iteration?
Should I use rows instead of coloumns?

_
Had to rework the Code, now the "names" are hyperlinks to images, but the problem remains the same ( I tried developers code suggestion) :

```
                               JSONObject json = gallery.getJSONObject(i);
                                // Loop for ListView
                                String jr_cover = json.getString("cover");
                                String jr_title = json.getString("title");
                                String jr_desc = json.getString("desc");
                                // Loop for Links
                                JSONArray pics = json.getJSONArray("bilder");

                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put("id",i);
                                //values.put("links",value);
                                for (int j=0;j<pics.length();j++)
                                {

                                values.put("link("+j+")",pics.optString(j));
                                }

String SQLiteDataBaseQuery = "INSERT INTO images_table (id,cover,title,desc,imgurl) VALUES('"+i+"', '"+jr_cover+"', '"+jr_title+"', '"+jr_desc+"', '"+values+"');";
                                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQuery);
```

What I get is 1 cell with the following values in it "link(2)=http:.... link(3)=... link(4)=" How can I separate them when I'm reading out the links between the link(i)?

Comment: Are you using SQLite Database

Comment: I will suggest you to create two tables, store thumbnail and a unique id in one table and stores names in another table and link the names by thumbnail id as foreign key

Comment: @Developer: Yes, should I use something else? // Arshad: Well, than if I have 4-5x Arrays, I'll have 10 Tables? Isn't that a little messy?

Comment: @ibai.kar did you try my answer

Comment: @Developer: I'm trying it with GSON first, just to see how this one works. Yours is next!

Answer (score 0):

make 3 columns instead, id, thumbNail and names. save the JSONArray directly into names column as String.  i.e, names.toString();

you will have to convert the data every time though, whenever you fetch it from Database. 
You can use Gson library for the same.

here is an example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
// This can be any object. Does not have to be an arraylist.

String json = gson.toJson(myAppsArr);

// How to retrieve your Java object back from the string

Gson gson = new Gson();

DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(arrayString, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: so you say with GSON I can insert all the names in one coloumn/row and read them out when I want to?

Comment: with GSON you can convert array into json string and back and put that string into the name column.

Comment: ok, got it, now in my DB there is a Cell with {"values":[....]} - now how can I use this String from my DB? Because afterwards I need to split it up for a ListView. That's not a 100% clear for me, it's my first time with gson :)

Comment: i think , instead of a cell {"values":[....]}, make a cell called {"values":""} and insert the names  from  JSONArray names = json.getJSONArray("name"); in it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 void adddata(String[] nmslist) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("id", yourid);
        values.put("thumbnail", value);
        for(int i=0;i<nmslist.length();i++)
             values.put("name("+i+")",nmslist(i));
        db.insert(TABLE_Name, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hello there, had to rewrite the Code (check the Update) - with your Code it happens that in my DB there is 1 cell with all the names (now links) in it like "link(2)=https://.... link(3)=... link(4)=...." Can I read them out now and use them somehow?